# partition allocation to consumers

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is there a way to force kafka to always a consumer catering to a single partition.
Even if a consumer crashes ,leading to re-balancing - we have to somehow ensure that a consumer is not catering to more than a single partition.
This is to prevent complexity in our business aggregation and fault-tolerance logic - in trying to cater to a dynamic/unpredictable number of partitions.

Comment: I thought one partition is already be consumed by maximum of one consumer isnt it?

Comment: question is to force one consumer to always consume one partition and no more

Comment: I think read into this will help, https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#assign(java.util.Collection), sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 1):

You could look at implementing a custom [ConsumerPartitionAssignor](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerPartitionAssignor.java) and using that for your Consumers - this allows you to explicitly control partition assignments while still making use of group management functionality.

By overriding [subscriptionUserData](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerPartitionAssignor.java#L51) you should be able to propagate the current partition that this consumer reads from (or explicitly configure one in its config and forward that) to the group leader that decides who has to read from which partition during the rebalance.
In the rebalance you can then make sure to assign partitions as they were.

That being said, I am not sure that I'd recommend this approach, if you need to be this deeply involved with internals, you may not be using Kafka right. Maybe take a little time to reconsider your approach :)

Kafka also has the CooperativeStickyAssignor as of recent versions, which takes a lot of the "bite" out of rebalances, taking a look at that might also help mitigate your pain..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can deal with it using the subscribe way with automatic rebalancing within a consumer group. I see different problems.
If you have a topic with X partitions, you need X consumers in the same consumer groups in order to have each one getting one partition. During startup, it can happen that while other consumers are starting up, one of them gets more than one partition. It also can happen that when one or more consumers crash, one of the ones still alive gets more partition meanwhile the dead ones recover.
You have no guarantee of one consumer - one partition in each moment.
For this reason, the only way to go is to use assign instead of subscription (http://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#assign-java.util.Collection-).
Please note that in this way you have to specify the partition and you don't have the auto-rebalancing feature out of box working for you.